# Getting error when project move to online?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, i developed one project and move to server [ i mean online server] it is showing error , that is:

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

**Parser Error Message:** 
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error clearly said that, you are putting your site inside another site. so you need to make this virtual directory as a application in IIS level.

Comment: yes, chmika your right i place my project inside another one, now what i have to do so that it run, please help me

Comment: i place my application in a static site. when any link is click it redirect to asp.net pages

Comment: no sorry, i place static site in my application and move to online

Comment: you have to convert your virtual directory to application in the IIS

Comment: @Suryasasidhar:Hope you will vote for the accepted answer since you are eligible for it now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the access to IIS, you can follow the link to create virtual directory
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5adfcce1-030d-45b8-997c-bdbfa08ea459.mspx?mfr=true